# how to implement right to left spinner like slider in android

Tags: android, slider, spinner

I am working in one project in which i need spinner which include list of country for selection. when user click on country selection box i want to make a spinner like right to left slider shown in below image. so user can select any country from this slider type spinner.

How can i implement this type of custom spinner?

I know how to implement custom spinner by making a custom layout for spinner but i don't have idea how to implement this type of spinner.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I think it is not custom spinner may be it is Listview with search header in popup window.

Comment: @HareshChhelana sir can you suggest me some links to implement this type of slider?